# Using Python cURL to upload to SMB

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I am trying to covert the follow curl command in CLI to python:

> curl --upload-file some.file -u 'username:p@ssw0rd'
>   smb://192.168.0.1/C$/local/path

Which works fine! But I can not get it to work with pycURL or requests in python.

*note: I do not want to use pySMB.*

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly are you seeing when you can't get it to work?

Comment: File "upload.py", line 11, in <module>
    c.perform()
pycurl.error: (3, '')
OR (if I add / at the end of the upload location)
File "upload.py", line 11, in <module>
    c.perform()
pycurl.error: (67, '')
Remember I am trying to upload to SMB, not http. But this is support from cURL 7.4.